# Waiting in Ionic 2 typescript for local storage promise to resolve before continuing

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ionic2, json-web-token

I have an Ionic 2 application in which I would like to implement a logout functionality. I want to set the value of a Json Web Token to null in local storage and then after the value is set, send the user to the login page.

I am having an issue where the application is not waiting for the value of the JWT to be set before taking the user to the login page. This is a problem because on the login page, I have a function to log the user in automatically if they have a valid JWT. Because the program is not blocking and waiting for the value to be set in storage, the user is logged back in immediately after logging out.

How can I wait for the value of the token to be set before sending the user back to the login page?

Log out functionality:

```
logout() {
this.storage.ready().then(() => {
    this.storage.set('token', '').then(data => {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
    });
});
```

CheckAuthentication functionality:

```
    checkAuthentication() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {

    this.token = value;

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.token);

    this.http.get('apiURL', { headers: headers })
      .subscribe(res => {
        resolve(res);

      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });

  });

  });
  }
```

IonViewWillLoad:

```
  ionViewWillLoad(){
 //Check if already authenticated
    this.auth.checkAuthentication().then((res) => {
        console.log("Already authorized");
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("Not already authorized");
        this.loading.dismiss();
    });}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can do here.

First off, I would refactor the code to make it a little more readable. If you see how I have the functions below, you'll notice that we're taking advantage of what promises naturally give us in that we can chain them together without having to nest our `then()`s.

In `checkAuthentication()`, you don't need to create the Promise like you were. You can just return the http Observable as a promise. If the the http call was successful, then the promise will resolve. If the http call fails, then the resulting promise will reject.

Lastly, I would try using `ionViewDidLoad` instead of `willLoad`.

```js
logout() {
  this.storage.ready()
    .then(() => this.storage.set('token', ''))
    .then(data => this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage))
}

checkAuthentication() {
  return this.storage.get('token')
    .then((value) => {
      this.token = value;

      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', this.token);

      return Observable.toPromise(
        this.http.get('apiURL', { headers: headers })
      );
    });
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.auth.checkAuthentication()
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("Already authorized");
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Not already authorized");
      this.loading.dismiss();
    });
}
```

Comment: The issue was unrelated to the code I posted here. The logout function I implemented was not running when the logout button was clicked. This is because I was editing the wrong typescipt file. Thank you for the refactoring suggestion however.

Answer (score 0):

In the logout function it should remove token rather than set it empty ''. Because the token still exist in the storage after logout.

```
this.storage.removeItem('token')
```